# is there a path in the complex plane such that z^z is not equal to 1 as z->0?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

Is there a path in the complex plane such that $$\lim_{z\to0}z^z\neq1\,?$$

In other words, I would like to approach $(0,0)$ in such a way that $f(z)=z^z$ will result in something different from 1. So far every path I tried gave me 1 as result.

I know that if I pick $y=0$ then: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y^x=0$$
but I would like a path where $y\neq0$

Comment: $z^{z}$ is not uniquely defined. If you define it as $e(z log(z)$ where  $log (z)= \ln |z|+ i arg(z)$ and $0\leq arg(z) \leq 2\pi$ then the limit is 1. Your example is not valid.

Comment: well, I know its not uniquely defined and sorry for not stating I was talking about the branch where 0≤arg(z)≤2π. Can you prove that the limit is 1 for every path in the complex plane ???

Comment: Yes, the limit is then 1 in whichever z approaches 0, so any path will give limit 1.